# Limitar Input a um intervalo de valores

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou criando uma pequena lojinha que venderá camisas de um evento e a venda das camisas serão limitadas a no máximo 4 camisas por pessoa, então preciso que no campo em que é definido o numero de camisas que a pessoa deseja comprar seja limitado a 4.

Com o input type number eu consigo setar este valor mas se a pessoa digitar o valor ao invés de utilizar o controle criado pelo campo ela consegue facilmente adicionar um valor maior.

Como faço para fazer com que o campo só aceite os valores 1, 2, 3 ou 4 lembrando que o valor mínimo é 1 e o máximo é 4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não é preciso Javascript:

```html
<form action='#'>
  <input type='number' value='20' min='1' max='4'/>
  <button type='submit'>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Eu testei isso mas nao funciona como expliquei, experimente colocar o valor a mão sem utilizar as setas do campo, você facilmente consegue coloca um valor fora do especificado (9 por exemplo)

Comment: @DarkMedia Mas o formulário não é enviado caso o input seja inválido. Pode [testar aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/rnxn/mhw3oqgr/) colocando um valor acima de 4 e tentando enviar.

Answer (score 3):

Tente realizar o bind do evento onchange a uma função javascript que irá verificar a mudança do campo input e sempre que o mesmo for alterado faça a verificação do valor do campo input, algo deste tipo:

```
$("#caixa_texto").bind('input propertychange', function(){
    if($(this).val() > 4){
         $(this).val() = 4;
    }else if($(this).val() < 1){
         $(this).val() = 1;
    }
});
```